# How can I solve this error? -> VIDEOIO(cvCreateFileCapture_AVFoundation (filename)): raised unknown C++ exception

Tags: opencv, video

I am a beginner of OpenCV, and I am currently doing OpenCV Tutorial 3.0.

While doing "Video Input with OpenCV and similarity measurement" part of the tutorial, I found the error below:

"VIDEOIO(cvCreateFileCapture_AVFoundation (filename)): raised unknown C++ exception!

Could not open reference ../data/Megamind.avi"

What does the error mean?

The part of my code is here :

```
stringstream conv;

const string sourceReference = "../data/Megamind.avi", sourceCompareWith = "../data/Megamind_bugy.avi";
int psnrTriggerValue, delay;
conv << argv[3] << endl << argv[4];       // put in the strings
conv >> psnrTriggerValue >> delay;        // take out the numbers

int frameNum = -1;          // Frame counter

VideoCapture captRefrnc(sourceReference), captUndTst(sourceCompareWith);

if (!captRefrnc.isOpened())
{
    cout  << "Could not open reference " << sourceReference << endl;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Try passing full qualified paths instead of relative paths.